# How can I prints all powers of n in range with recursive method?

Tags: c, recursion

How can i print all integer powers of n greater than or equal to p where they are in range [minInt maxInt]?

Think you have a method like this:

```
void showPowersInRange(int x, int p, int minInt, int maxInt){}
```

And you can set x, minInt, maxInt. For example :

x = 3 minInt = 20 maxInt = 83

Expected output :

```
27
81
```

It must be recursive method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, written directly into SO editor

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showPowersInRange(int x, int p, int minInt, int maxInt) {
     if (p > maxInt) return;
     if (p >= minInt) printf("%d\n", p);
     showPowersInRange(x, p*x, minInt, maxInt);
}

int main(void) {
    showPowersInRange(3, 1, 20, 83); // start p with 1
}
```

---

Version with no overflow issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
// assume all arguments are positive
void showPowersInRange(int x, int p, int minInt, int maxInt) {
     if (p > maxInt) return;
     if (p >= minInt) printf("%d\n", p);
     if (p > maxInt / x) return; // no need to calculate p*x, and risk overflow
     showPowersInRange(x, p*x, minInt, maxInt);
}
 
int main(void) {
    showPowersInRange(3, 1, 20, 83); // start p with 1
    puts("---");
    showPowersInRange(247, 1, 1, 1000000000); // start p with 1
}
```

Comment: Why not test it then? You took time to type, format, and even think of it, but couldn't open up an editor or use one of those online IDEs to test the code.

Comment: [Tested now](https://ideone.com/CJZlao), it works :-)

Comment: Minor: `p*x` risks overflow. Infinite loop possible with select values.

Comment: Thanks @chux-ReinstateMonica, [fixed](https://ideone.com/C53M5e)

Comment: The output in case of overflow is unwarranted: the next power of `x` is obviously greater than `maxInt` so just return. As a matter of fact, there is no need for a special case on `INT_MAX`, `if (p > maxInt / x) return;` suffices.

Comment: There are 2 more special cases to handle for positive numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program for powers of a positive integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
// assume x is positive
void showPowersInRange(int x, int p, int minInt, int maxInt) {
     if (p > maxInt)
         return;
     if (p >= minInt)
         printf("%d\n", p);
     if (x > 1 && p <= maxInt / x)
         showPowersInRange(x, p * x, minInt, maxInt);
}

int main() {
    int x, minInt, maxInt;
    printf("Enter x minInt and maxInt: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &minInt, &maxInt) == 3) {
        if (x < 0) {
            printf("x must be positive\n");
        } else {
            // start enumeration at 0 for 0 and 1 for non-zero values of x
            showPowersInRange(x, x != 0, minInt, maxInt);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```